# Search script file for parameters

Tags: c#, regex, powershell

I am looking for a way in C# to search a PowerShell script file for its parameters.

The top of my PowerShell script contains the following:

```
 [CmdletBinding()]  
    param(
    [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$Domain,
    [Parameter(Position=2, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$SIPDomain,
    [Parameter(Position=3, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$RegistrarPool,
    [Parameter(Position=4, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$ExchangeServer,
    [Parameter(Position=5, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$OU,  
    [Parameter(Position=6, Mandatory=$false)] [string]$SleepTime="10",
    [Parameter(Position=7, Mandatory=$false)] [bool]$CreateAA=$true,
    [Parameter(Position=8, Mandatory=$false)] [bool]$CreateSA=$true
    )
```

For each parameter I would like to store its position, whether its mandatory, type, variable name and default value if it has one. I would also like all but the variable to be compulsory as some scripts may have very basic parameters e.g.

```
param($name, $test)
```

For the example above, I would like an object that looks something like this:

Position Mandatory Type Variable DefaultValue(the bit after the '=')

```
1 $true String $Domain
2 $true String $SIPDomain
3 $true String $RegistrarPool
4 $true String $ExchangeServer
5 $true String $OU
6 $false String $SleepTime 10
7 $false bool $CreateAA $true
8 $false bool $CreateSA $true
```

I have spent a few hours attempting to get the right splits using regex, but I think the pattern is a bit too complex for me.

Really appreciate some help on this.

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: What version of powershell are you using?

Comment: In this case 3.0 but I sometimes use 2.0 depending on MS product version I am managing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following code to get the same output you specified:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(script, @"\s*\[Parameter\(.*?\)\].*?,");

foreach (var match in matches)
{
    string result = Regex.Replace(match.ToString().Trim(), @".*Position=(.*?),\s*Mandatory=(.*?)\).*?\[(.*?)\](.*?)(=""(.*?)""|\s*),", "$1 $2 $3 $4 $6");
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

This first matches for the lines that contains `Parameter` pattern. Then for each line of those it extracts the needed output.

**Update**
To get the data into variables, use the following line inside the `foreach` loop:

```
 var datamatch = Regex.Match(match.ToString().Trim(), @".*Position=(.*?),\s*Mandatory=(.*?)\).*?\[(.*?)\](.*?)(=""(.*?)""|\s*),");
```

then use `datamatch.Groups[1]`, `datamatch.Groups[2]`, and so on to get the strings, after that Parse strings to the types you need. For integers for example use `int.Parse`

Comment: Thanks for your help that's pretty close!!!

 The output is as follows: 
=1 $true string $Domain =2 $true string $SIPDomain =3 $true string $RegistrarPool =4 $true string $ExchangeServer.

Need to just get rid of the '=' in front of the position number. 

Also can I easily get that data in to an object/table variable/array so I can pull the data out later?

Apologies if terminology is bad. I come from a PowerShell background and I am just learning C#.

Comment: @AndrewMorpeth I had a typo error, forgetting the `=`. It is now fixed. Also, updated the answer on how to get them in variables.

Comment: Cant quite figure out the table bit. How can I store in an object variable that looks like the table in the original post? Headings: Position, Mandatory, Type, Variable, DefaultValue

Comment: @AndrewMorpeth I was away for a while however, if you still need this, there are many different ways for storing data, you could have an array of a struct/class that encapsulates all the fields of a row which is useful in having all relevant/related-data stored together, or you could have a dictionary of certain key (Position/Variable Name) and the value would be a struct encapsulating other values, this is useful in indexing/searching by key ... cont. in next comment

Comment: @AndrewMorpeth Alternatively you could have multiple arrays, one for each data  field (an array for position, an array for Mandatory, and so on), this useful for example in getting statistics on the data of each field but you should figure out a way to attach related-data if you need this. There are other approaches, depending on your application. For parsing you have to determine data-type for each field (int/bool/string/...) and then use built-in type-parsing-from-strings methods to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

This only works in V3:

```
(@'
[CmdletBinding()]  
    param(
    [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$Domain,
    [Parameter(Position=2, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$SIPDomain,
    [Parameter(Position=3, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$RegistrarPool,
    [Parameter(Position=4, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$ExchangeServer,
    [Parameter(Position=5, Mandatory=$true)] [string]$OU,  
    [Parameter(Position=6, Mandatory=$false)] [string]$SleepTime="10",
    [Parameter(Position=7, Mandatory=$false)] [bool]$CreateAA=$true,
    [Parameter(Position=8, Mandatory=$false)] [bool]$CreateSA=$true
    )
'@).split("`n") |
foreach {$_.trim()} | sc testparams.ps1

$AST = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::
ParseFile('c:\testfiles\testparams.ps1',[ref]$null,[ref]$null)

$AST.ParamBlock.Parameters | 
 foreach {
   $IsMandatory = $_.Extent.Text -match 'Mandatory=\$true'
   $Position = $_.Extent.Text -replace '.+Position=(\d+).+','$1'
   New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                                    Name = $_.Name
                                    Type = $_.StaticType
                                    Position = $Position
                                    Mandatory = $IsMandatory
                                    }
        } | Select Name,Type,Position,Mandatory | ft -auto

Name            Type           Position Mandatory
----            ----           -------- ---------
$Domain         System.String  1             True
$SIPDomain      System.String  2             True
$RegistrarPool  System.String  3             True
$ExchangeServer System.String  4             True
$OU             System.String  5             True
$SleepTime      System.String  6            False
$CreateAA       System.Boolean 7            False
$CreateSA       System.Boolean 8            False
```

Comment: That looks like it would work nicely for PS, but I want the query to happen from within a C# app that reads the param's from a .ps1 script.

Comment: Sorry, I only know PS.  The AST parser should be available to use in C#, but I can't give you the code for that.  I'll remove the answer it if it's not helping.